# How to stick an image and text together, and below them a line, then more text, and then another line?

Tags: formatting, wrapfigure

I'm trying to get this (An image was supposed to be on the upper LHS corner):
[image]

With this code

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.25\textwidth }
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{utm logo colores.PNG} 
\end{wrapfigure}


\begin{center}
Universidad Tecnológica de la Mixteca 

Instituto de Física y Matemáticas

Protocolo de Tesis
\end{center}

\rule{15cm}{.01cm}

Nombre del alumno:
No. matrícula:

Carrera: 

Nombre de la tesis: \textbf{}

\rule{15cm}{.01cm}

\tableofcontents
```

I got this:

[image]

Could someone please help to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are using a floating environment, when you acutally are looking for an absolute position for your image. Have you tried just adding the image directly in either a table or ideally a two-column environment?

Comment: @MarkusG. nop. I didn't even know that one could include images in a table. I've noticed that you used something different: {minipage}.

Comment: Yes, I had the columns environment from the beamer package in mind. But that simply uses minipages. A solution with a table would have worked as well, but tables have a tendency to add empty spaces that are often undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the image and the text in two side-by-side minipages.

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 \begin{document}
     \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
        \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
        \centering
        Universidad Tecnológica de la Mixteca 
        
        Instituto de Física y Matemáticas
        
        Protocolo de Tesis
    \end{minipage}

\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}

Nombre del alumno:
No. matrícula:

Carrera: 

Nombre de la tesis: \textbf{}

\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}

\end{document}
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**
You can align the text between the two lines in one of two ways. Both have advantages and disadvantages as you will see.

The first is a `tabbing` environment, which is a bit reminiscent of a typewriter:

```
\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}
\begin{tabbing}
    Nombre del alumno: \= \kill % for the length
    Nombre del alumno: \> Name\\
    No. matrícula: \> Number\\
    Carrera: \> Something\\
    Nombre de la tesis: \> \textbf{Title of the thesis}
\end{tabbing}   
\vspace*{-2mm}
\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}
```

The other is a simple table, but this will also *indent* the text a bit:

```
\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}
    
\vspace*{2mm}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Nombre del alumno: & Name\\
    No. matrícula: & Number\\
    Carrera: & Something\\
    Nombre de la tesis: & \textbf{Title of the thesis}
\end{tabular}   
    
\vspace*{2mm}
\noindent\makebox[.97\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.0pt}}
```

Please note the empty lines below and above the `\vspace*{}` commands, which ensure that the table is acutally between the two lines and not next to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept my answer, to make sure others can see that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Do you know how to make the text to start, not right after the ":" but to be aligned with the other text above and below? See for example: **Licen...** started at a specific point.

Comment: I added some more code to give you some examples on how to achieve this.

Comment: Double thanks. I didn't notice a difference between the displays of both, but I've chose the second since I see it more clear to know what's going on.